# Blocking CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

My AuthenticationFilter is blocking all my css and js files but ONLY on the main page `localhost:8080`

How do I remove this? I need to be able to load the js and css on the main page.

AuthenticationFilter

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/";

    boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("loggedUser") != null;
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);

    if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

Web.xml

```
   <!--Make sure the user is logged to access the other pages-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.atp.Model.Filter.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> <!-- The 'static' content -->
```

Comment: How do you know it's the `Filter` who is blocking them? 

Any error msg or logs? Can you show some?

Comment: It's the filter because if I put the css on the page it works. I dont  think is anything else.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):6 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/".

Answer (score 0):

This made it work. I don't know if it's the propper way of not....

```
   //don't block css and js
    else if(request.getRequestURI().contains("js") || request.getRequestURI().contains("css")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I looked again in your code after you posted your solution the picture seems to be clear.

In your web xml, you specified..
All the request URI containing `.css`, `.js`, `.img`, etc as extension, must be mapped to a servlet, and on each servlet you applied a filter. So all your static resource calls are also being passed through `filter`, which you actually don't need.

And then in your solution, you are catching those requests (the else-if condition you posted as answer) and then doing nothing but just passing it on to it's next step i.e. the requesting client (browser).

So, you created a trap, you caught your animal, and you freed him.

This could have been done in a better way by just not catching those animals which you don't want to.

So, remove the servlet mapping of .css, .img, etc. and also remove the else-if condition to check if it is css or js, it should still work.

Comment: I thought my servlet mapping was making sure those types passed and not actually blocking. I just want to block anything that is not those types.

Comment: yes. I want avoid people acessing other pages without logging first. After I made my filter I couldnt access the js,css, images , etc... in all pages

Comment: as you can see ` <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` will block all access to what is not root page (login). including css,js,etc..

Comment: Are your endpoints showing `.jsp` ? I mean the in the url bar, can user see .jsp extension or it is done by servlet

Comment: So what are your urls being shown to user? Is it like rest-full services like /student, /student/123, /student/123/edit something similar to it?

Comment: And, is your server serving only JSON responses, or it also serves html (or jsp) pages too?

Comment: pages too. I think I will just keep this way. it works.

Comment: What else you can do is, create a excluded filter, and mention them before actual url-pattern in your web.xml because filters follows orders in which they are defined.